# Why does my actionPerformed method stop working when I add additional code?

Tags: jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to code the actoinPerformed for a JButton using the code below.  If I cut off the code at the "count++", everything works fine up to that point. However, when I add the part to check for a winner, nothing happens when I click the button.  The methods I am using (i.e., placeXToken, placeOToken, and checkWinner) all work fine when I use them in a command line version of the program, so I don't think the problem is there.  I thought it might have something to do with trying to open JOptionPanes within the actionPerformed method, so (as you can see) I changed them to command line prints, but I still get the same problem.  I am totally lost as to why it stops working when I try to add the checkWinner part.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    colInput = Integer.parseInt(action);
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        instructionslabel.setText("<html>It is " + names[otherIndex] + "'s turn."
                + "<br/>Please select where you would like to place your token.</html");

        placeXToken(colInput);
    }
    else {
        instructionslabel.setText("<html>It is " + names[randIndex] + "'s turn."
                + "<br/>Please select where you would like to place your token.</html");

        placeOToken(colInput);
    }
    count++;

    //Checks to see if there is a winner or a tie each turn
    if (checkWinner() != null) {

        //what to do in case of a tie
        if (checkWinner() == notoken) {
            System.out.println("tie");
            /*int tie = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    getParent(), "<html>The game ended in a tie.<br/>Would you like to play again?</html>",
                    "Tie Game",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (tie == 0)
                main(null);
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),
                        "Thank you for playing.  Goodbye.", "Goodbye.", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                close();
            }*/
        }

        //what to do if X wins
        if (checkWinner() == xtoken) {
            System.out.println("xwin");
            /*int xwin = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(),
                    names[randIndex] + " won the game.Would you like to play again?",
                    "X Win",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (xwin == 0)
                main(null);
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),
                        "Thank you for playing.  Goodbye.", "Goodbye.", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                close();
            }*/
        }


        //what to do if O wins
        if (checkWinner()== otoken) {
            System.out.println("owin");
            /*int owin = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(),
                    names[otherIndex] + " won the game.Would you like to play again?",
                    "O Win",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (owin == 0)
                main(null);
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),
                        "Thank you for playing.  Goodbye.", "Goodbye.", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                close();
            }*/         
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the checkWiner method.  Perhaps someone might be able to point out an error I may have made when converting it from use for command line to use for GUI.

```
public static Icon checkWinner() {

    // Checks for horizontal win
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row = row++) {         
      for (int col = 0; col < 5; col =col++) {
        if ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)
        && (slotlabels[row][col+1].getIcon() != notoken)
        && (slotlabels[row][col+2].getIcon() != notoken)
        && (slotlabels[row][col+3].getIcon() != notoken)
        && ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row][col+1].getIcon())
        && (slotlabels[row][col+1].getIcon() == slotlabels[row][col+2].getIcon())
        && (slotlabels[row][col+2].getIcon() == slotlabels[row][col+3].getIcon())))

            return slotlabels[row][col].getIcon();  // returns the token (X or O) of the winner
      }
    }

    // Checks for vertical win
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col =col++) {      
      for (int row =0; row < 4; row = row++) {
            if((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+1][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+2][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+3][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+1][col].getIcon())
        && (slotlabels[row+1][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+2][col].getIcon())
        && (slotlabels[row+2][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+3][col].getIcon())))

                return slotlabels[row][col].getIcon();  // returns the token (X or O) of the winner 
      }  
    }

    // Checks for diagonal left-top to right-bottom win
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row = row++) {
      for (int col = 0;col < 5; col = col++) {
            if((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+1][col+1].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+2][col+2].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+3][col+3].getIcon() != notoken)
            && ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+1][col+1].getIcon())
            && (slotlabels[row+1][col+1].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+2][col+2].getIcon())
            && (slotlabels[row+2][col+2].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+3][col+3].getIcon())))

                return slotlabels[row][col].getIcon();  // returns the token (X or O) of the winner
      }  
    }        

    // Checks for diagonal right-top to left-bottom win
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row = row++) {
      for (int col = 3; col < 8; col = col++) {
            if((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+3][col-4].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+6][col-8].getIcon() != notoken)
            && (slotlabels[row+9][col-12].getIcon() != notoken)
            && ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+3][col-4].getIcon())
            && (slotlabels[row+3][col-4].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+6][col-8].getIcon())
            && (slotlabels[row+6][col-8].getIcon() == slotlabels[row+9][col-12].getIcon())))

                return slotlabels[row][col].getIcon();  // returns the token (X or O) of the winner
      }  
    }

    // Checks to see if the game resulted in a tie
    boolean tie = true;
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row = row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col = col++) {
            if (slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() == notoken)
                tie = false;
        }
    }
    if (tie == true)
        return notoken;

    // Otherwise, there is no winner and no tie, so do nothing with this.
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was careless in changing over from command line (where I was making 3x4 cells in the grid to make it look nice) to the GUI (where each slot is just a +1 away from the previous), and I ended up leaving the incrementation in the for loops as "row = row++" and "col = col++".  Java does NOT like this.

Answer (score 0):

Start your application in the debugger of your IDE and set a breakpoint for the line `count++`. The debugger then allows you to step through the code so you'll see each line that is executed and it will also show you the values of all visible variables.

That way, you should be able to see where the code breaks.

If you don't have an IDE, the cheap workaround is to add `System.out.println()` with some useful text everywhere so you can see where the output stops.

Lastly, you may want to wrap the code in a big `try/catch` block with

```
catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

at the end so you can see any exceptions which the code might throw on the console.

Comment: I am using the Eclipse IDE, but the debugger doesn't really give me any useful information that I can find.  I also tried your other two suggestions.  The series of console messages just told me what I already know - the program hangs when it gets to the checkWinner portion.  The try/catch did not print any Trace to the console, and the program just hung at the same point.

Comment: In which line does it hang?

Comment: the line: `if (checkWinner() != null) {`.  I would suspect the checkWinner method that this calls, but it works perfectly when I use it in a command line version of the program.

Comment: I just added the portion of the code for the checkWinner method to see if anyone can find an error there.

Comment: Use `F5` or "Step Into" to debug a method that is called.

Comment: Ok, that gave me more information, at least.  When it gets to the first conditional check of my checkWinner method - the line that reads `if ((slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)` - I get an error that pops up for JLabel.class Line: 357 for the method JLabel.getIcon that says "Source not found".  At that point, every time I click the "Step Into" button, it goes back over that same line and gives the same error.  Any idea what is going on now?

Comment: I suggest to avoid such complex lines to make debugging easier/possible. Create a local variable and assign `slotlabels[row][col].getIcon()` to it. That way, you can step over the line and see which icon you get back. Also note that `==`/`!=` doesn't work reliably in Java for objects. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to do what you suggested, but it's not exactly simple.  You see, slotlabels is an 8x7 2D array of image icons.  Initially, they are all set to an image icon called notoken, and then through gameplay, they are changed to either an image icon called xtoken or an image icon called otoken.  The checkWinner method has to compare them in sets of four adjacent slots (horizontally, vertically, and diagonally) after each change to see if there are four identical image icons in a row.

Comment: I did try changing the format from `(slotlabels[row][col].getIcon() != notoken)` to `(!slotlabels[row][col].getIcon().equals(notoken))`, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I doubt that it hangs in this method. Try to step over it. As for your `equals()` problem: Try to wrap the icon in a class `Token` which contains a type (empty, x, o) plus an icon. Then you can implement your own `equals()` which just compares the type.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was, and I could just kick myself.  Look at the nested for loops in my checkWinner method.  I had "row = row++" and "col = col++".  This is because in my command line version, I was adding 3 and 4, respectively, to pad out the cells of the grid to make it look nice.  When I switched to a GUI, I knew that I had to change it to just adding 1, but I wasn't careful enough about it.